# Merge Statement with temp table

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.merge_test (
   r_obj refcursor,
   _ldeptid character varying
) RETURNS refcursor
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'  COST 100.0  VOLATILE AS $function$
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblCumulate;    
   create temp table tblCumulate (
      lCompid varchar(10),
      lOpenCount int default 0,
      lClosedCount int default 0
   );  
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblOpen;  
   create temp table tblOpen (
      lOSID SERIAL,
      lCount numeric(24,0),
      lCompid varchar(100)
   );  
   MERGE  into  tblCumulate CUM using (select lcompid,lCount from tblopen) as OP   
      on CUM.lcompid=OP.lcompid
      when matched
         then update set cum.lOpenCount=op.lcount  
      when not matched
         then insert (lCompid,lOpenCount) values op.lcompid,op.lcount);
   open r_obj for  
      select * from tblCumulate;  
   return r_obj;  
END;
$function$;
```

when I execute (Run) this procedure showing following error.

```
ERROR:  "tblcumulate" is not a known variable
LINE 41:  MERGE  into  tblCumulate   CUM  temp
```

Comment: You are using some 3rd party PostgreSQL fork or modified version. Please identify the exact database server you are using. `SELECT version()` would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `MERGE` statement in PostgreSQL.

Consider using [`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html).